# Is Gradle's cache thread safe?

Tags: maven, gradle

So one of the problems with Maven is the cache up on your Continuous Integration server. Jenkins, for example. If I have 15 or 20 builds going and some of those depend on others, I've got a problem because I don't know which jars are going to be installed into that local repo at the precise time they are pulled by each build, if they are sharing the same repo. If they don't then you have ALOT of redundancy.

My question is: Does Gradle suffer from similar issues? The gradle cache seems more advanced than a Maven repo but it doesn't seem to me like this issue is easily solvable. In order to manage this situation, you would have to start off by differentiating which local artifacts came from a remote repo and which were constructed locally. That way you could at least remove the redundancy of those jars that you are pulling down from Artifactory or MavenCentral or whatnot.

Comment: I had an idea pertaining to this. Create a job that downloads all the dependencies EXCEPT those the builds generate and call that one the static local repo. We could even write in something that detects dependency changes beforehand and updates the static local repo along with using a lock file.  Then just add that one to the regular build. That would cut down the duplication some.

Comment: This idea doesn't work on Maven because it only considers two types of repository. Local and remote. Remotes are always copied into locals leading right back to massive redundancy.